# Page is not loading at time in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my web page i am using panel then div. panel is loading first and then div tag, but I want two at a time. I tried Ajax update process and java script Loading image but not working.

please help me.

```
       <div class="container-fluid contentStart" >
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div data-layout='{"type": "border", "hgap": 3, "vgap": 3}' class="layout     mailVertical">

      <asp:Panel ID="pnlRefDet" runat="server" class="layout mailVertical" >
       ....
       </asp:panel>
              <div class="west" style="background-color:#FAFAFA; width:32%"  runat="server"    id="divMessageInbox">
                 .....
             </div>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How about posting your code...

Answer (score 0):

You can put both in table then it will load at once

```
<table>
  <tr>
     <td>
          panel goes here
     </td>
  </tr> 
  <tr>
     <td>
          div goes here
     </td>
  </tr> 
</table>
```

Comment: if i am using table CSS not working.both are dispalying side by side. left side Inbox i.e,div tag, right side body i.e,panel.

Comment: Then you need single row of table with two cells

Comment: You might be missing something as this is not the expected behaviour